# AjaxControlKit in .NET 2.0 from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on a project which was developed in Visual Studio 2005 (.NET 2.0). I have Visual Studio 2008 and on opening the solution the files are converted to older framework.

But the project uses a AjaxControlKit which I guess is not available by default in ASP.NET 2.0 and hence it throws an error that a reference/library is missing on conversion and compiling it in 2008.

Any library/ reference can be added to solve this ? where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the error during the conversion process or when you attempt to compile the converted application?  Have you tried removing the reference and re-adding it?  Removing it before conversion, upgrading to .NET 3.5 and adding the newer, [3.5-dependent version](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit) back in?

Comment: I get the error when I compile the converted application. 

I'll try adding the reference and see.

Answer (score 3):

the AjaxControlToolkit is not included in the base .Net framework, you need to install it on your development machine.

You can find more information on the [AjaxTookit site](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit)

Comment: But by default ASP.NET 3.5 has the ajax kit. I have visual Studio 2008

Comment: I believe that it is an extra download from the ASP.NET AJAX web site (or Codeplex).

Comment: yes it is, ajax extensions are installed with vs 2008, not the control toolkit.